# How to validate empty value which is double type in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I have the jsf input text as double type in pojo class.
I want to validate that field with `empty check`. By default in page load the value comes as 0.0 in the text field. Once I clear the value (i.e empty value) and click submit button, the text field is not getting validated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to appear empty than you can change from `double` (primitive) into `Double` (Object)

and set the field to `required="true"`